# How to remove or disable a CSS framework class

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

Hope this isn't a dup, but I couldn't find a solution for this.

I'm using Vuetify which comes with this specific class and styling:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px)
.v-tabs__container--fixed-tabs .v-tabs__div, .v-tabs__container--icons-and-text .v-tabs__div {
    min-width: 160px;
}
```

I need to completely remove the `min-width` style. NOT set it to `0px` or any other value, it just needs to be GONE.

How can I do that?

EDIT
Here are things I don't want to do.
 `none` for `min-width` is invalid

[This is what the original looks like at 160px. not good](https://nimb.ws/bf32Md)

[This is what auto looks like, also not good](https://nimb.ws/zGu80y)

[Ahhh, this is what it looks like with the style removed!](https://nimb.ws/aqU0Jp)

Comment: You can use min-width : none; if you wanna remove completely! Or auto same as in answer.

Comment: Can't use `none` getting an invalid property value

Comment: You might consider providing a [working demonstration](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the layout issue. Needing to remove the CSS declaration rather than resetting it could indicate an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/234388) and there may be a more effective solution.

Comment: Maybe min-width: unset; will help.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that there are only two options here:

1. Find where that style is being generated and remove it from the stylesheet.
2. Write a style that would overwrite that style in your own stylesheet.

That being said, I don't think that option 1 is generally considered to be a good idea, and option 2 is what you said you didn't want to do.

I probably would go for something like:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px)
.v-tabs__container--fixed-tabs .v-tabs__div, .v-tabs__container--icons-and-text .v-tabs__div {
    min-width: auto;
}
```

Just curious, why don't you want to go with min-width:0px; ?

Also, if there is a way to actually do what OP is talking about that I don't know about, I'm looking forward to being proven wrong here.

Comment: thanks, but nope doesn't work. I updated the OP with screenshots.

Comment: "why don't you want to go with min-width:0px"?